# Array and For each Function Not Working

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach, get

Please can someone help me, I am trying to use the array function to give an overall variable a positive or negative value, based on the results of checkboxes.

The checkbox question is, which of the following reindeer exist, so for every reindeer that is correct I am looking to give the variable $finalvalue an increment value. Then leaving an IF function at the end to say if the wrong reindeer is ticked, give a decrement value, but as well as the increment values for the right ones.

I have attached the code below, every time I use it, the value does not increase as desired or is not cumulative for every correct reindeer.

Thanks.

HTML FIRST

```
Which of the following are of Santa's Reindeer?(You can select more than one answer)<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="reindeer" value="Rudolph">Rudolph<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="reindeer" value="Prancer">Prancer<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="reindeer" value="Dancer">Dancer<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="reindeer" value="Ronald">Ronald<br>

<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

PHP SCRIPT RECIEVER SIDE

```
$reindeer=$_GET['reindeer'];

$type=array("Rudolph","Dancer","Prancer");
foreach($type as $reindeer){$finalvalue = $finalvalue+2;};

if ($reindeer=="Donald"){$finalvalue = $finalvalue-6;}


print "$finalvalue";
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: should the if, be inside the foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $input = $_GET['reindeer'];
    $valid = ["Rudolph","Dancer","Prancer"];

    # Debug input..
    echo 'Raw input data:<pre>';
    var_dump($input);
    echo '</pre>';


    if(is_array($input)){
        foreach($input as $reindeer){
            if(in_array($reindeer, $valid)){
                echo 'user supplied multiple answers and '.$reindeer.' is listed in $valid. </br>';
                $finalvalue = $finalvalue+2;
            } else {
                echo 'user supplied multiple answers and '.$reindeer.' is listed <strong>not</strong> in $valid. </br>';
                $finalvalue = $finalvalue-6;
            }
        }
    } else {
        # This code should never execute unless the user changes the html code.
        if(in_array($input, $valid)){
            echo 'user supplied 1 answer and '.$reindeer.' is listed in $valid. </br>';
            $finalvalue = 2;
        } else {
            echo 'user supplied 1 answer and '.$reindeer.' is listed <strong>not</strong> in $valid. </br>';
            $finalvalue = 0;
        }
    }


    echo $finalvalue;

?>
```

Comment: unfortunately this answer has returned me the following error command, do you have any other recommendations?

    
   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in        /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php_class/PHP Project/naughtyornice.php on line 58

Comment: That means that the input is not an array. I've updated the code to compensate for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you are correct, it is a string, how would I accommodate for this in the future? Would I simply type in ///$type=string("rudolph","dancer","prancer") etc.? Thank you very much

Comment: In your HTML code, change **name="reindeer"** to **name="reindeer[]"**

Answer (score 0):

```
Which of the following are of Santa's Reindeer?(You can select more than one answer)<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="reindeer[]" value="Rudolph">Rudolph<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="reindeer[]" value="Prancer">Prancer<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="reindeer[]" value="Dancer">Dancer<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="reindeer[]" value="Ronald">Ronald<br>

<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">



 $input = $_GET['reindeer'];
 $valid = ["Rudolph","Dancer","Prancer"];


 foreach($input as $reindeer){
      if(in_array($reindeer, $valid)){
            $finalvalue = $finalvalue+2;
       } else {
            $finalvalue = $finalvalue-6;
       }
  }
```

Notice the brackets in the html. Adding those brackets to the name of the input makes it come as an array. Thus, produces much cleaner and minimal code.

Comment: True, however the user is able to change the html code and post the answer making it show critical information you don't want to display. Always sanitize user input.

Comment: would you like to give an example? his use case is extremely simple

Comment: Using Firefox or Chrome, inspect element, remove the brackets in the name and then submit your results. Even if his case is extremely simple, better to learn it the right way then the hard way.